# Attached property is not serialized into XAML

Tags: xaml, serialization, flowdocument, attached-properties

I'm using XAML serializer to save a flow document into a file.  I also want to assign some attached properties to certain elements.  So I created an attached property of type Guid whose parent is a TextElement.  It doesn't seem to get serialized.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK guys, I resolved the issue.  It was about the owner type parameter of the RegisterAttached.  I was setting it to the target type that I intend to set the property on, it should be the same class that actually implements the attached property.  I think this is used by the XAML serializer to get more metadata when it needs to.  So now, it works.  Just wanted to share.

Comment: It is just for 3.5, sine in 4.0 there are other approach for attached properties. http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2009/05/18/xaml-in-net-4-0-attached-properties-iattachedpropertystore-and-attachablepropertyservices.aspx